# Modify DOM while page is rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on a page that has a large number of <inputs> and takes a *very* long time to finish rendering. I cannot change the contents of the page, only add JavaScript (including inline code). I need to prevent the user from interacting with the form until it has fully loaded, preferably by temporarily disabling the <inputs>. Is this possible?

Comment: You could hide them with CSS, and un-hide them when the document is ready

Comment: Or break your page down so that there aren't so many inputs per page, do you really need all of the inputs on one page? Hide some until previous ones are filled or move some to another page/div.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I do not have control over the content of the page. I can only add inline JS or CSS.

Comment: You can use something like this: `document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;` to block the user from entering some info in the input, and after page has loaded you can set it to `false`. read more in: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp

Answer (score 1):

Like Matthew said in his comment, hide your inputs with CSS first. Then add a class that shows them once the document is ready. Assuming you have jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form[name=someUniqueName]').addClass('loaded');
});
```

And then your CSS:

```
form[name=someUniqueName] input {
  display: none;  // or visibility: hidden; if you want it to take up it's space
}

.loaded form[name=someUniqueName] input {
  display: initial; // or whatever you want it to be
}
```

Of course, for your form selector, ideally you would have an id or class name that your could use. As long as it's unique to that form on that page.